# undefined variable in lambda expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

I am having trouble understanding the following function.

```
def make_adder(n):
    return lambda x: x + n

plus_2 = make_adder(2)

plus_2(5)
>>> 7
```

In this function, what does x represent and how does this not result in an error because x is undefined?

Comment: it is a parameter to the function. the same as if you did `def foo(x): <do something with x>`

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function which, given `n`, returns *a function* which accepts an argument x and returns `x + n`. This is called a higher-order function. It doesn't yield an error because you're explicitly returning another function which expects an argument.

Comment: so the function make_adder returns not the addition of N, rather a function that then accepts X, and calling that returns x + n. Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly right. It's a way to make your functions more general -- you can now make an `add_one`, `add_two`, `add_seventeen` with just a change of parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The x represents the parameter that the lambda expression receives, this is why it's before the ":".

When you do the `plus_2 = make_adder(2)` call, the lambda expression substitutes the n with the parameter of the function (2), so now `plus_2` equals `lambda x: x + 2`. When you call `plus_2(5)` the lambda expression is evaluated, substituting the x with the function parameter (5), so the result is 5 + 2 = 7;

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions are awesome. They allow you to define higher-order functions inline. The general format is `lambda args: expression`. In this case, `x` is the argument passed into the lambda function. Because `make_adder` returns a lambda function, whatever you pass into `make_adder` is set as `n`. So when you pass in `make_adder(2)` you get a lambda function that adds 2 to the argument (`x`).

Decomposing your original snippet:

```
def make_adder(n):
    return lambda x: x + n

plus_2 = make_adder(2)  # returns lambda x: x + 2

plus_2(5)  # executes lambda expression, x + 2 with x=5
```

Starting from scratch:

```
5 + 2  # 7

plus_two_fn = lambda x: x + 2  # Add 2 when you call plus_two_fn(x)

plus_two_fn(3)  # returns 5 (3 + 2)


def plus_num_fn(num):
    return lambda x: x + n  # Allow you to define plus "any" number


plus_one_fn = plus_num_fn(1)  # lambda x: x + 1

plus_one_fn(2)  # returns 3 (2 + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line below:

```
plus_2 = make_adder(2)
```

we're binding the integer object `2` to `n`.

After that when `plus_2` is called using the argument:

```
plus_2(5)
```

the integer object `5` would be bind to `x` when the `lambda` expression is executed.

This is the runtime execution flow. Since there is no ambiguity or errors in this whole process, the program runs just fine and outputs `7`.

Now, to answer your question: the variable `x` represents whatever value is passed to `plus_2()` as per your naming.